# How to show the "Display Settings" window from C#

Tags: c#, winapi

How can I show the Windows Display Settings (Resolution Settings) window from C#. (the one where you can adjust screen resolutions)

I have found a way to [change the display settings via p/invoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx) but all I want to do is show the Dialog Settings window that comes with Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `Process.Start("control", "desk.cpl")`?
Here is an MSDN page on launching control panels: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144191.aspx

Comment: on Windows XP that will open the window but by default the 'Themes' tab is selected. I wonder if there is a way to cause it to show the 'Settings' tab initially.

Comment: I think I found it "control desk.cpl,,3"

Comment: Ah yes. I found an MSDN page (probably the same one you did) describing it all.  I don't suppose this works for XP: Screen resolution: %windir%\system32\control.exe desk.cpl,Settings,@Settings?  My only concern with the ordinal way is on the off chance another tab has been added in by a shell extension.

Comment: Great.  I guess it's canonical enough to enjoy backwards compatibility.

Comment: good point about the shell extension. I will test the other way.

Answer (score 0):

For your information, all the syntaxes proposed here run on Windows XP, but the only one that is accepted by 360 Total Security is

```
control.exe desk.cpl,,,0
```

Thanks Patrick to have solved my problem with 360.

On the command line, you can also type :

```
desk.cpl,,,0
```